# Convert byte[] to String (unknown byte[] type)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

So I'm a pretty amateur programmer, trying to follow some examples for creating a small auditing system for this application I'm working on.

The framework we're using (StrataFrame) on top of C# .NET 4.0 requires that the auditted values be stored as byte arrays. I followed a small example of their forum that had me do this;

```
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new                       System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        System.IO.MemoryStream outstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        foreach (DataColumn dc in jobHeaderBO1.CurrentDataTable.Columns)
        {
                if (!dr[dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original].Equals(dr[dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current]))
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(outstream, dr[dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current] + " " + dr[dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original]);

                    Auditor.ShouldAuditDataChanges(jobHeaderBO1);
                    Auditor.InsertAuditEvent("JOB HEADER", dc.ColumnName + " changed.", outstream.ToArray());
                    Auditor.InsertAuditRecords(jobHeaderBO1);
                }
        }
```

So that all works as far as I can tell- records get inserted to the appropriate table and when I look at it it's a bunch of garbage. So now I need to present that garbage to the user!

I found a few examples that say just do things such as:

```
  string oldv = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(adf.adf_OldValue);
  string newv = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(adf.adf_NewValue);
```

When I print out oldv and newv, the values don't display properly. Some of the fields that stored text mostly show fine, but dates and numbers don't. I guess the issue is that I have no idea what type of encoding it is, and I can't find out either. Any suggestions?

Comment: We will also need a sample of the data so we can find out what encoding it is using

Comment: You need to work out what the encoding of the data in the database is.  Reverse engineering this is not the way to go. Find somebody who knows and ask them.

Comment: You realize dates and numbers may not be stored as strings, and therefore trying to interepret as strings makes no sense?

Comment: I didn't realize that depending on the type of data it would be converted differently, no.